# Using Stash within Stash to pass an entry_id for Safecracker

Tags: safecracker, stash

I'm using Stash in a few ways.  First, as a layout template (.layout-account.html). Second, to get variables for testing.  But I'm struggling with the final part.

I have two channels - Users (via Zoo Visitor) and Firms.  I want the user to be able to edit their own firm via a safecracker form.  There exists a Playa field within the Zoo Visitor channel called "Firm".  It let's my client choose the correct firm that the user belongs to from the Firms channel.

I have a Low Variable called {lv_stash_get_firm_id}.  This calls a {channel:entries} to get the value of the Playa field for their firm.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="zoo_visitor" limit="1" author_id="{logged_in_member_id}" status="HCAA_Members-id5|Open" parse="inward"}
    {exp:stash:set name="firm_url"}
        {embed="includes/.get_firm" entry_ids="{member_firm_name:child_ids}"}
    {/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

The template .get_firm looks like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="firms" fixed_order="{embed:entry_ids}" fixed_order="0|{embed:entry_ids}" dynamic="no" disable="member_data|pagination|categories" status="not closed" parse="inward"}
{entry_id}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

My template for manage-firm-info looks like this:

```
{embed="layouts/.layout-account" site_top="public_top" security="yes"}
{lv_stash_get_firm_url}
{exp:stash:main_content}
            {if last_segment == "success"}
                <p class="profile-update-success">Your information has been updated.</p>
            {/if}

            {exp:safecracker channel="firms" entry_id="42" return="/profile/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success" parse="inward"}
                ... Stuff ...
            {/exp:safecracker}
{/exp:stash:main_content}
```

The .layout-account controls all of the header and footer stuff, etc., and also calls {exp:stash:main_content}

Everything works fine if I use:

{exp:safecracker channel="firms" entry_id="42" return="/profile/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success"}

or (assuming the entry_id is in the URL)

{exp:safecracker channel="firms" entry_id="{segment_3}" return="/profile/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success"}

But obviously that won't work as the entry_id won't be the same for each user.  Also, I'd rather not show the entry_id in the URL as someone could then modify it and change someone else's firm.

So I thought I would try to use Stash to set the firm_id and them pass it into the Safecracker form like this:
    {exp:safecracker channel="firms" entry_id="{stash:firm_url}" return="/profile/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success"}

However, that doesn't work.

If I add {exp:stash:firm_url} prior to the Safecracker form, it spits out the correct entry_id.  So it's getting that far.  But it's not getting to the Safecracker form as it gives me an error that I need a valid entry to edit.

I'm guessing this is a parsing or syntax issue but I just can't quite get there.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so no matter what I did I couldn't get it to work as it was (even though it was outputting the correct value outside of the Safecracker form).

I came across another post and one thing someone said at the end was "I guess I was overthinking it."  So I started to go back through and look at everything.

I was already getting a value for the permissions from the Zoo Visitor channel using

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
    {exp:stash:set name="permissions"}{cf_member_firm_permissions}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

So I added another call in there to get my firm_id

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details} {!-- This finds out whether they are editor or not --}
    {exp:stash:set name="permissions"}{cf_member_firm_permissions}{/exp:stash:set}
   {exp:playa:children field="member_firm_name"}
        {exp:stash:set name="firm_id"}{entry_id}{/exp:stash:set}
   {/exp:playa:children}    
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

I was able to use entry_id="{exp:stash:firm_id}". The additional bonus is that it also saved me from having to run the extra embed to pull the entry_id from the Firms channel.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass a variable in a parameter to any EE template tag, you need to add `parse="inward"` to the tag. For example:

```
{exp:stash:set name="firm_id"}1{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:safecracker channel="firms" 
   entry_id="{exp:stash:firm_id}"
   return="/profile/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success" 
   parse="inward"
}
...
{/exp:safecracker}
```

EDIT: another way you pass a variable to another tag is via a placeholder variable inside `{exp:stash:parse}`:

```
{exp:stash:set name="firm_id"}1{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:parse}
    {exp:safecracker channel="firms" 
       entry_id="{stash:firm_id}"
       return="/profile/{segment_2}/{segment_3}/success"
    }
    ...
    {/exp:safecracker}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

In either case, make sure the variable you are passing doesn't contain line breaks since those are captured too; E.g. this will fail when you try to pass as a parameter:

```
{exp:stash:set name="firm_id"}
1
{/exp:stash:set}
```

If you want to remove line breaks automatically, use the `trim="yes"` parameter on either set or get:

```
{exp:stash:set name="firm_id" trim="yes"}
1
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Comment: Hi Mark - thanks for your feedback.  Actually, through my research I had found that I needed that (it's actually in my example above but just scrolled off the screen).  I have tried both entry_id="{exp:stash:firm_id}" and entry_id="{stash:firm_id}.  I've also tried entry_id="[{stash:firm_id}]" and entry_id="[{exp:stash:firm_id}]" because I saw an example while doing research.  I just keep getting "You must specify a valid entry to edit" message.  Yet if I drop {exp:stash:firm_id} above the safecracker, it gives me the firm_id.  And if I put in "42" for entry_id, it pulls the correct info. :(

Comment: I just tried a simple {exp:channel:entries} and added {exp:stash:firm_id} as the entry_id.  Even with parse-"inward", I'm not getting any results with that either.  I've got to be over looking something somewhere!  :(

Comment: Passing a variable like this definitely works, but there is another way to do it - see updated answer and also the note at the bottom